# reactjs - Popup : Showing a popup withouth clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-popup

Im tying to show up a pop up whit the following code :

```
const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
```

Im handling the show/setpopup by this way :

```
 <Popup open={showPopup} onClose={() => setShowPopup(false)} modal>
    <span> Popup content </span>
  </Popup>


  {meta.error === 'codigo 2 fatores incorreto' ? (
    setShowPopup(true)
  ) : (
    <Popup style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>.</Popup>
  )}
```

When it drops in the case (meta.error === 'codigo 2 fatores incorreto') he drops in a loop with the following eror : (Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. ) , someone knows how to solute it ?
I used this doc https://react-popup.elazizi.com/component-api/

whole component [WORKING] :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ErrorMessage, useField } from "formik";
import { StyledTextInput, StyledLabel, StyledIcon, ErrorMsg } from "./Styles";

// Eye for password
import { FiEyeOff, FiEye } from "react-icons/fi";

//pop up style.css 
import '../assets/css/popup.css'
// Import popup lib
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';


function MyComponent() { 
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  setState(true);
  return (
    <Popup model
    trigger={open => <MyComponent open={open} />}
    position="right center"
    closeOnDocumentClick
  >
    <span> Popup content </span>  </Popup>
  );
}



export const TextInput = ({ icon, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  const [showpass, setShowpass] = useState(false);
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    if(meta.error === 'codigo 2 fatores incorreto'){
    setShowPopup(true);
    }
  }, [meta.error])
  

  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <StyledLabel htmlFor={props.name}>{props.label}</StyledLabel>
      {props.type !== "password" && (
        <StyledTextInput
          invalid={meta.touched && meta.error}
          {...field}
          {...props}
        />
      )}
      {props.type === "password" && (
        <StyledTextInput
          invalid={meta.touched && meta.error}
          {...field}
          {...props}
          type={showpass ? "text" : "password"}
        />
      )}
      <StyledIcon>{icon}</StyledIcon>
      {props.type === "password" && (
        <StyledIcon onClick={() => setShowpass(!showpass)} right>
          {showpass && <FiEye />}
          {!showpass && <FiEyeOff />}
        </StyledIcon>
      )}
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <ErrorMsg>{meta.error}</ErrorMsg>
      ) : (
        <ErrorMsg style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>.</ErrorMsg>
      )}

      <Popup open={showPopup} onClose={() => setShowPopup(false)} modal>
      {close => (
      <div className="modal">
        <button className="close" onClick={close}>
          &times;
        </button>

        
             
      </div>
    )}
    
  </Popup>
    {meta.error === "codigo 2 fatores incorreto" ? (
      !showPopup ? ( setShowPopup(true)) : ("") // <-- Only set state if not true 
 ) : <Popup>.</Popup>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: JSX is not the place where you set the state. Can you share the whole code for that component? You must be getting this error somewhere in the component and that’s where you had to set the state for pop up.

Comment: @SanishJoseph  Ok im gonna edit it and post the whole component

Comment: I think an easier way is not to manage the state manually and directly pass in `meta.error === "codigo 2 fatores incorreto"` into `<Popup open=`

Comment: @GaryOng I tried it , but it not open my pop up :/ , I think the lib dont render it Im still trying to read the doc but im not finding where to use something like state or something like it . doc:https://react-popup.elazizi.com/component-api/

Comment: @GuilhermeCavenaghi passing directly should work. I think you should not put `modal>` as the modal api does not have a open prop for this library

Comment: @GaryOng I tried to remove modal as you said , but it seems that putting meta.erro inside the <popup open= / don work in the lib, I can be wrong but as for me its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, it seems whenever `meta.error` matches your string, it'll constantly call `setShowPopup(true)` because the state updated - and calling that function causes the re-render, during which I assume `meta.error` is still 'codigo 2 fatores incorreto'.

I believe you could do something like the following to stop the re-rendering.

```
{meta.error === "codigo 2 fatores incorreto" ? (
    !showPopup ? setShowPopup(true) : "" // <-- Only set state if not true
) : (
    <Popup style={{visibility: "hidden"}}>.</Popup>
)}
```

I may be wrong though, and I may be misunderstanding the snippet.

Comment: thanks for the answer , what im trying to do is simple I thing but im not being able to figure out what to do , I will explain always when the meta.error is equals to  "codigo 2 fatores incorreto" I want to show a pop up , I changed my code by the one you answered me , now the error is gone but the pop up is not appeareng , once again thanks for the answer

Comment: Altought the principle in this comment is indeed right, we should never use a `setState` inside a render method. Even conditionally. We should use `useEffect` for that.

Comment: @juliomrc yeah I got it and I changed my code thanks for coming by

Comment: @adi73434 I changed a bit and it got right , thanks buddy

Comment: I felt there was something unideal about setState in the render function. I'd follow juliomrc's answer; I would've done something similar within class-based React, but didn't know to use `useEffect()`.

Answer (score 2):

We should **never ever** use a `setState` inside the components render method. For class components, that is inside the `render()`, for function components, that is anywhere inside `return()` or in the component body, like here:

```
function MyComponent() { 
   const [state, setState] = useState();
   setState(true);
   return (...);
}
```

This will always cause an infinite loop.

1. `setState()` triggers re-render.
2. Re-render runs the component code again and triggers `setState()`. Go back to 1.

React provides tools to handle your case, such as [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Instead of

```
{meta.error === "codigo 2 fatores incorreto" ? (
        setShowPopup(true)
      ) : (
        <Popup style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}></Popup>
      )}
```

You should have

```
export const TextInput = ({ icon, ...props }) => {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    if(meta.error){
      setShowPopup(true);
    }
  }, [meta.error])
  
  return (
    ...
    <Popup style={{visibility: "hidden"}}>.</Popup>
  );
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , I tried to implement it on my code , but now it dont show the pop up I should try to call the function ?(if I should where I can call it ?) , btw thanks for the answer at least I learned how to use a JSX correctly

Comment: also I changed the component, if you want to take a look  , once again thanks for the answer you helped me a lot : D